# Error in installing NS 2 in linux in function erase()

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

[image]
Here is the Error i am getting while installing NS2 in version 2.35 in ubuntu 14.04. 
What is the solution of the error ?

Do I need to re-install the whole setup or specific module because this error happen after some time.

I have tried 2 time and both time got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy solutions :

1) Use the 'Nov 2014 update' of ns-allinone-2.35 : ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz .

Which can use all gcc/g++ versions, 4.6 ... 4.9.2 .

Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

2) Using the 2011 version : sudo apt-get install g++-4.4

And then build with :

cd ns-allinone-2.35/ && export CC=gcc-4.4 CXX=g++-4.4 && ./install

-